# UIPickerView disappearing on Simulator at build

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I have made a Tab Bar app and have added a UIPickerView in the XIB file. But when I come to building it it is not visible on the tab item. Just to note it is hidden or 'de-alphred' and also I have connected it to the Delegate. I used this [Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbBI6Ig04KU).

Comment: If you're not going to share your video publicly on youtube, please remove the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems delegate issue.

Add this line to ViewDidLoad method and it will appear:

```
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
```

P.S. Also in .h file you should adopt [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate) protocol like this:

```
@interface DomainInput : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out what the issue was and yes, in the interface I forgot to connect the 'data source' to the UIPickerView, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine that you have connected to the delegate but you have to define delegate methods in your code. I mean you have to write code in UIPickerView delegate methods when you write code then and then pickerview will appear in simulator.